# Is there a service or framework in Native AWS for task management?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am looking for a service or framework in Native AWS which given, a csv file, creates a task and process that task asynchronously and returns a task id or job id to the client and notifies the client when the task is completed. Some requirements for this:

- Client should be able to check the progress of the task by job id at any time.
- Processing of entire task can take more than 15 mins.
- There should be a way for clients to see the reasons of failures.
- All the business logic would be at line item level. (this is the only thing developer should care about)

Is there any in-built service or framework for that in Native AWS? I know one can build this kind of service using some SQS, Lambda, SNS, Dynamodb but I am just looking if there is a already available AWS offering for it, which can do all of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest service to this concept is [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html).

However, it would just be **one component** of a solution. You would still need to create the **compute** component by using Amazon EC2 or AWS Lambda. You would need to build the **interface** for users, add authentication, notifications, etc.

**Bottom line:** There is no AWS service that does what you describe. However, there are the building blocks if you wish to create one yourself.

Comment: Thanks John for your reply. Are there any particular advantages you think are with step functions than without it?

Comment: Step Functions can take care of much of the logic (eg creating a job, tracking job status, triggering Lambda functions) but you will still need to build the "task management system" you desire. Given that your tasks can take more than 15 minutes, it would not be suitable for a single Lambda function. Therefore, you'd either need to split-up the tasks into sub-components, or do your compute on Amazon EC2 (in which case Step Functions is not particularly beneficial). You might want to look around for open-source task systems that do most of what you want, to save you most of the effort.

Comment: The examples you mentioned like creating a job, tracking job status. Don't we still need lambdas for that? It's just each step would correspond to a lambda, right. I have thought of 1 solution which doesn't use step functions and does this thing of task management. I am thinking of making at as a service. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c3GLNASqVi_ZpSQ4xcM9KA7h2E3zCmLi/view?usp=sharing. What do you think are the shortcomings of this solution that would be solved by Step Function?

Comment: Sure, you can write it all yourself. Step Functions could provide the "overall view" of a task as it progresses through each step, so you don't have to write the 'task tracking' parts yourself. It's up to you!